# A question about ordered fields

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, ordered-fields

Let F be a non-empty ordered field. Can F be a finite field and if so does there exist a simple example of such an F?

Answer (score 1):

In an ordered field, $0 < 1$. So $a < a + 1$ for any $a \in F$. But if $F$ is finite, what happens to $1 + \cdots + 1$ eventually?